# Google oAuth is sometimes returning error "redirect_url_mismatch" and sometimes redirecting correctly

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

Working sometimes, tried in 3 different browsers (firefox, chrome, brave) both incognito and normal, couldn't find any consistency.

Working [Redirecting correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk7X9.png)

Not Working [Returning Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIlbZ.png)

Video of me trying the same.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/25913091?key=f1db04ef423b20b206f703836b0b640e

Tech stack : Node, Express.

API Code:

```
const clientId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirectUri = "https://apex-customer.devstree.com/auth/social/";

// Route for initiating the OAuth flow
router.get("/auth-google", (req, res) => {
    const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    const url = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&response_type=code`;
    res.redirect(url);
});
```

Any explanation for this or any documentation regarding this.